# Why my python file what can access on pycharm can't work with in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, pycharm

I can success to run the code about the beautifulsoup method on pycharm, but the vscode tell me what my bs4 isn't exist when I run on the IDE. I used virtual environment of the annaconda and then have chosen the same interpreter of the pycharm on vscode.

Comment: Are you sure that you selected anaconda virtual enviroment in the vscode? How do you run your python file in the visual studio code?

Comment: Yes, I absolutely choose the right virtual environment . the code can be run in the terminal with the python file successfully in the visual studio code, but that code can't be run when I clicked the button --run code.